# Native application crashes on Android L

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a native application that always worked on Android KitKat with both **Dalivik** and **ART** runtimes, but it now crashes on **Android L** with the following trace:

```
E/art(12810): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.mylib.example", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "issetugid" referenced by "mylib.so"...
D/AndroidRuntime(12810): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(12810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12810): Process: com.mylib.example, PID: 12810
E/AndroidRuntime(12810): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "issetugid" referenced by "mylib.so"...
E/AndroidRuntime(12810):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:364)
E/AndroidRuntime(12810):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:610)
```

Is ART runtime in Android L different from KitKat? There is no new NDK available yet, therefore, how to avoid this crash, because it seems that the function `issetugid` is no longer supported.

Comment: It is possible that seeing the relevant code might help here?

Comment: It simply fails to load the native lib.

Comment: Ahh, OK. I'm an idiot. I didn't see the error.. which is plain as day in your brief trace... Ignore me!

Comment: Also there is a bug now https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=168&q=issetugid&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary

Comment: Is there going to be a fix soon or should we flash back to 4.4.4?

Comment: According to the comments on Issue 168, this should be fixed if the native lib is compiled with new Android NDK r10.

Comment: @arsalank2 Are you talking about when compiling with Android-5.0 SDK or running on Android L preview/Android L?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Compiling your native lib with r10. However, in the final Android 5.0 this issue seems to be fixed.

Comment: @arsalank2 So I am guessing you have now received the OTA update for Android 5.0? No issues with r10? That is good. Have you answered your own question?

Comment: I installed the updated manually by downloading the official system image from https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has been fixed in the final Android 5.0 release. There is no need to re-compile existing binaries.

However, if the native lib is compiled with target **android-21**, it fails on previous Android versions (< 5.0)

Comment: arsalank2, so you just kept your target the same?

Comment: Yes, I used android-19 to support previous versions.

Comment: So you compiled it twice? or are you saying you targeted android-19 to support all devices including Android 5.0? How did you target all devices?

Comment: No, I compiled it once with target android-19 to support all the devices.

Comment: So compiling with a target of android-19 works on all API levels such as API 9+?

Comment: Not necessary, you have to be careful and only use the API that is supported on the min target API. To be on the safe side, you should compile the code with the same min target API, e.g. android-9.

Answer (score 0):

I think i may have the answer, please correct me if iam wrong.I had faced similar issue and now its fixed (or i have found a workaround rather)

while registering native method to JNI, there are two ways of doing it.

1) Implement JNI_OnLoad() method in your .cpp file and register your native methods with the 
   appropriate classes.
   Check- http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#native_libraries
   example - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SimpleJNI/jni/native.cpp

2) there is a particular naming convention to follow for the native methods, where the class path (including package) have to be added.
  Check - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html#wp615
 Here we need not implement any method. The JVM discovers the native method from the symbol names it self from the binary.

The first method doesn't seem to work in Android ART runtime (ART is Optional in kitkat and it will be the only runtime in Lolipop).I am not not sure why it doesnt work. but i think the reason is because the way ART performs.(The bytecodes are converted and cached during install time itself instead of runtime, so that app runs faster). So since the native libs are not loaded (on_load is not called) the conversion to machine code fails at some point

Use the second method to register natives. it should work.
Only disadvantage is now your function names will be and long and will look horrible (i bet none of the function will fit in 100char limit).bye bye function name readability.

Hope this helps

Cheers,
Shrish

Comment: What you are calling "the second method" is the way JNI on Android was originally done; if you are really running into a 100-character limit you might want to rethink your namespace for readability.  More importantly, it seems unlikely that these comments have much of anything to do with the rather specific error in the question.

Comment: More specifically, the problem at the core of this question is one which occurs when a function changes from being dynamically linked to being declared either inline or as a macro, such that its implementation should be automatically included in the build of the client program and not provided by the dynamic library.  The poster's existing build assumes it will be provided by the dynamic library at runtime.  But their new device assumes it should be included in the client program (and does not provide it in the library), thus incompatibility results.